# Young adult fantasy book about a girl with gray eyes and powers related to metal

Tags: identification-request

I read this book about 10 years ago in either late elementary/middle school. It was a light fantasy novel (perhaps YA) and I'll try to summarize all the main points I remember.

- The main character was a girl named Petra and she had gray eyes (which was important to the book) and powers related to metal/machinery. She has a pet metal spider who drinks oil.
- Her father left home a long time ago to help and never came back. Around the start of the story I believe she receives his eyes from palace messengers
- She meets a boy who is Romani and he teaches her to throw daggers, which she's uncannily good at
- This same boy is extremely talented at pickpocketing because he has a power that gives him "invisible fingers" and a small backstory is explained for this that goes thousands of years back (I think it had something to do with this man who had his fingers cut off, but I can't be sure)
- This girl goes to the palace to work for the prince in disguise as a maid (the aforementioned boy works there as a stableboy and so does his sister, but as a maid if I remember correctly)
- Petra gets tossed around a bunch and eventually ends up working for this woman named Iris(?) who works with dyes and almost no one likes her and I believe she's also very ugly. They come up with a new color for the arrogant prince in this story
- The last two vague details I remember are something with a clock tower and also a metal beating heart that hurts to touch

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*The Cabinet of Wonders* (2008) by Marie Rutkoski, first book of the *Kronos Chronicles*.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2850734-the-cabinet-of-wonders):

> Petra Kronos has a simple, happy life. But it's never been ordinary. **She has a pet tin spider named Astrophil who likes to hide in her snarled hair and give her advice**. Her best friend can trap lightning inside a glass sphere. Petra also has a father in faraway Prague who is able to move metal with his mind. He has been commissioned by the prince of Bohemia to build the world's finest astronomical clock.
>
> Petra's life is forever changed when, one day, her father returns home – blind. The prince has stolen his eyes, enchanted them, and now wears them. But why? Petra doesn't know, but she knows this: **she will go to Prague, sneak into Salamander Castle**, and steal her father's eyes back.
>
> **Joining forces with Neel, whose fingers extend into invisible ghosts that pick locks and pockets**, Petra finds that many people in the castle are not what they seem, and that her father's clock has powers capable of destroying their world.

---

Found with the Google query `fantasy novel petra gray eyes site:goodreads.com/book`.